# how to Enable Debug logs in All components in WSO2 IS?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

how to Enable Debug logs in All components in WSO2 IS?

I want to track code running.

Could you tell me what config I need add ?

Thanks

henry

Answer (score 3):

You can turn the logs in WSO2IS by making all the logs into debug level in Log4j configurations. To do that

- Go to ***//repository/conf*** directory
- Open ***log4j2.properties*** file
- In there you can find ***loggers=AUDIT_LOG, trace-messages, org-apache-coyote,...*** field make sure to add all the Java package names there
- Change the log level in every package to '**DEBUG**'. as an example

```
logger.org-apache.name = org.apache
logger.org-apache.level = DEBUG
logger.org-apache.additivity = false
logger.org-apache.appenderRef.CARBON_LOGFILE.ref = CARBON_LOGFILE
```

After that you can find that all the debug logs have being visible in the terminal.

Comment: Yes, I find it have 30 more packages in logger, and I need add these define lines for every package, then,I need too many define lines.   Do you have top-level define which can open all packages log ONCE ?